# Placing images in a fixed layout GTK2

Tags: c, graphics, gtk

I have an application that is attempting to do the following:

- Create a `GTK2` top level main window
- Add a fixed frame into the main window for absolute positioning of widgets
- Create a matrix of `GtkImages` that will be used to display animated `GIFS` and static `JPEGS`
- On start-up the static `JPEGS` picked randomly from a list will fill the matrix
- When an event happens the matrix will be filled with animated `GIFS`
- When the animation is over possibly different `JPEGS` will again be displayed in the matrix

Run time errors are happening only when two or more of the randomly selected `JPEGS` are placed in a row of the matrix.

Here is an example of such a run time error:

```
(wrong:3909): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
```

If each image of the row are unique no run time errors occur.

Code snippets and run time output are as follows:

```
/*
 * Compile me with:
 *   gcc -Wall -o wrong wrong.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0)
 */

/* header includes */

/**** prototypes ****/
/********************/

typedef struct
{
    unsigned int pixel_width, pixel_height;
    gchar fileName[20];
    GtkWidget *image;   
}symbol_t;

symbol_t symbols[] =
{
    { 118, 107, "images/LO.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/L1.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/L2.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/L3.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/H1.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/H2.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/H3.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/H4.jpg", NULL },
    { 118, 107, "images/H5.jpg", NULL }
};

GtkWidget *frame;       /* for absolute positioning of widgets */
GtkWidget *window;


int Init( void )
{
    /* initialize random number generator */
}

static void destroy (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit ();
}

GtkWidget *SetupWindow(gchar *data, const gchar *filename)
{
    /* setup top-level window setting the background to the image contained
       in *filename and return window widget
    */

    return(window);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int y, i, pos_x, pos_y;    

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    Init(); // init random number generator
    window = SetupWindow("Broken", "images/background.jpg");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

    frame = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

    /* setup symbol jpgs */
    for( i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
    {
        /* load each symbol image into memory */
    symbols[i].image = gtk_image_new_from_file( symbols[i].fileName ); 
    }

    /* display some symbols */
    pos_y = 150;
    pos_x = 187;
    for( y = 0; y < 5 ; y++ )  /* first row - 5 symbols */
    {
    i = (unsigned int)(random()%9);
    printf("Symbol[%d] [%s]\n", i, symbols[i].fileName);
        gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), symbols[i].image, pos_x, pos_y);
    pos_x += symbols[i].pixel_width;
    }

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

**Run time errors when two or more matching symbols ( images ) are placed on the row:**

> ```
> [chim] ~/source/matrix > ./wrong 
> Symbol[1] [images/L1.jpg]
> Symbol[7] [images/H4.jpg]
> Symbol[0] [images/LO.jpg]
> Symbol[7] [images/H4.jpg]
>
> (wrong:3909): Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
>
> Symbol[5] [images/H2.jpg]
>
> (wrong:3909): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
>
> (wrong:3909): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
> ```

When this occurs some of the images in the row are empty ( white ).

**Output when no matching symbols ( images ) are placed on the row:**

> ```
> [chim] ~/source/matrix > ./wrong 
> Symbol[1] [images/L1.jpg]
> Symbol[6] [images/H3.jpg]
> Symbol[3] [images/L3.jpg]
> Symbol[0] [images/LO.jpg]
> Symbol[4] [images/H1.jpg]
> ```

And in this case all images are displayed properly.

Any suggestions about how to fix and what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you place the image into another widget, it becomes owned and managed by that (parent) widget -- you can't add it to more than one widget.

The simple way to get this to work is to load the image with `gtk_image_new_from_file()` each time you want to add it to the window.  If you don't want to do that, maybe you can use something like `gtk_image_new_from_image()` to copy the image prior to adding it to the widget.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I appreciate it. I will check it out in the morning.

Comment: See "Why does my program leak memory, if I destroy a widget immediately after creating it?" at [GTK+ common questions](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-question-index.html) for a very concise description of how resources are managed -- it is a little bit weird (but nice).  The key thing to be aware of is that someone has to delete these resources (such as images), or there will be a "leak".  In GTK+, this is primarily done by turning over ownership to a parent "container" which will delete the object when the parent is destroyed.  If you give the object to two parents, chaos ensues.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue has been resolved, but now I've got a memory leak. The [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750543/gtk2-application-memory-leak-using-multiple-images) is here if you can help with it as well.